# iOS ResearchKit swift documentation

Tags: ios, swift, documentation, researchkit

Where can I find documentation for ResearchKit using Swift? Does it exist? All I can find is documentation in ObjectiveC.

Example:
http://researchkit.org/docs/docs/Survey/CreatingSurveys.html

Answer (score 2):

As of right now, there is no swift documentation, but Ray Wenderlich does have a simple tutorial on his website at: http://www.raywenderlich.com/104575/researchkit-tutorial-with-swift
Also, the API reference page of the official ResearchKit documentation may help you, as it describes all of the ResearchKit defined classes, and is not specific to objective-c (http://researchkit.org/docs/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no specific Swift documentation. If you want to add Swift examples, I'd recommend making the pull request against the 'ios9' branch, which has full Swift 2.0 support.

In terms of the documentation generated from the headers, since the headers are all in Objective-C, we are unlikely to have a specific Swift version for it.

Comment: It is also worth noting that the `ORKCatalog` and `ORKTest` sample apps (they are part of *ResearchKit*'s main repository) are written in *Swift*.

Comment: Correction: only `ORKCatalog` is written in *Swift*.

Answer (score 1):

A guide came out in 2016 so I thought I would update this question. There is a guide that goes through all of the features of ResearchKit and shows sample code of each feature along with the explanation and screenshots. Here is the link for it: [Getting Started with ResearchKit](https://books.google.ca/books?id=d7JKDAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false). I was able to get a copy of it at my local library.